# get full 'path' by reflection (C#)

Tags: c#, reflection

Is it possible to get the full 'path' by reflection?

Example imagine I have the below classes / properties.

```
public class Member
{
    public string Name;
    public Address Address;
}

public class Address
{
    public string Line1;
    public string Line2;
    public string Line3;
}
```

---

Imagine I have an instance of this class named `m`.  Is it possible to get the full path as "Member.Address.Line1" (as string), by reflection, just by passing somehow `m.Address.Line1`?

Comment: can u post your class structure properly?

Comment: from what i am assuming Address is a public property of type IEnumerable<String> ?

Comment: @AppDeveloper I'm guessing it's actually a class with three members of type string

Comment: three member as in public string Line1 {get;set;}

public string Line2 {get;set;}

public string Line3 {get;set;}

Comment: Imagine if you would post actual code ? then others could actually guide and or point you in the right direction

Comment: Where are you "passing" `m.Address.Line1`? What is the type of `Line1`? Why are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: are you looking to find the file path of a specific .dll..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I don't really think that would help. You could do the class and member declarations easily enough. I'm more curious as to why it's needed.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Actually the last line is pretty clear he wants to know how to write a method `frobber` such that `frobber(m.Address.Line1)` returns `"Member.Address.Line1"`

Comment: it's not that clear right off the bat Conrad hence your edits the question should re-written in a much clear context.. happy holidays..!

Comment: get Full Path by Reflection I would automatically think something like this string fullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof("Name of .dll you are seeking path to")).Location;
//get the folder that's in
string theDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName( fullPath );

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: check my edited solution!

Comment: All: Sorry about the late replies, but I was away for New Year!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to use `Expression<Func<T>>` then yes, it should be simple.

Just do something like this:

```
 public string GetFullPath<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action) {
  return action.Body.ToString();
}

var fullPath = GetFullPath(() => m.Address.Line1);
```

That does not give you exactly what you want, but it will be VERY close, and you can remove the bits you don't want.

I'll dig around in that object a little more to see if there's a cleaner way to get you closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Works, though it does require some cleanup to the actual string returned, but it can be parsed easily.

Comment: For those who need only the last part, with a naive Substring:  `public string GetFullPath<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
        {
            var temp = action.Body.ToString();
            return temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf(')') + 2);
        }`

Answer (score 1):

No.

The problem is that when you pass the `m.Address.Line1` instance, all your method receives is the `Line` instance, and it has no way to find out which instances reference it.

You could, of course, make the method accept something like `MyMethod(m, "Address", "Line1")`, but that would likely defeat the whole purpose (hard to know since you didn't say why you wanted this)

You might have some luck with [`Expression<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx), though.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that "No" is indeed the answer to *Is it possible to get the full 'path' by reflection?* Its definitely possible in general though since things like Windbg and CLR Profiler can do this. Those tools however use unmanaged code to access the memory directly.

Comment: Was away for New-Year, sorry for the late reply - After some thinking, it makes sense that it is not possible as the `Line1` instance can be contained in various objects, and not just `m.Address`.

Comment: @luiscubal - Actually, it can be done via the `Expression<T>`, as explained in CubanX answers below. Gave it a try and it does work.

Comment: @KarlCassar Indeed. However, beware that if you do `var x = m.Address.Line1; MyMethod(x);`, the output will be `x`, not `m.Address.Line1`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first make sure I understand your question...   If you want to obtain the value of `m.Address.Line1` by passing a string such as "m.Address.Line1" to some function, then yes you can do that.  If you are trying to start with Line1 and navigate up the tree to see what objects reference it, then this is a much harder question and I can't help.

If it is the first case, then I do this in an article I wrote on CodeProject that fills in a text template.   The code itself is a bit complicated, so I won't post it here, but here's the link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/505428/A-lightweight-recursive-text-template-data-formatt

The code essentially splits the string that you pass in at each "." and recursively navigates down the object tree to locate the value you are looking for.  It also has some support for things like `IEnumerable` but only for filling in the template (that is, you can't navigate into a specific index of a list).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Even with the link anyone interested in this would have to download the code and hunt for it with pretty much no guidance

Comment: Michael I fail to see how this link helps the OP

Comment: I don't think this is what OP needs. His question looks more like "I have a certain variable, and I somehow want to know which other object instance it belongs to". Which, by itself, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Groo / DJ - yes, I can see that interpretation... obviously this wasn't how I interpreted..   I posted my response before luiscubal did, but after reading his response (and Conrad's comment) I edited my response to address this issue.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: not a problem Michael just trying to protect you from downvotes

Answer (score 0):

i have assumed "Address" is something that doesnt exist, as earlier you said that the Class has three string property! Line1, Line2, Line3

i have added One extra property "Name" that holds the name of the class, its quite same as having a control Name so we can tag objects on basis of that Name property,

additionally, if you need such output that u have to keep track of the objects created, for that i preferred a List type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Member
    {
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string Line3 { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    static class Program
    {
        private static readonly List<object> MyRefObjHolder = new List<object>();

        private static void Main()
        {

            Member m = new Member {Line1 = "line1", Line2 = "line2", Line3 = "line3", Name = "m"};

            Member n = new Member {Line1 = "line1", Line2 = "line2", Line3 = "line3", Name = "n"};

            MyRefObjHolder.Add(m);
            MyRefObjHolder.Add(n);


            string tmp1 = GetCompleteNameWithProperty("m.Line1");
            string tmp2 = GetCompleteNameWithProperty("n.Line1");
            Console.WriteLine(tmp1); // prints : Member.Line1
            Console.WriteLine(tmp2); // prints : Member.Line2
            Console.Read();

        }

        public static string GetCompleteNameWithProperty(string objref)
        {

            string[] obj = objref.Split('.');

            if (obj.Length < 2)
            {
                return null;
            }

            string className = obj[obj.Length - 2];
            string propName = obj[obj.Length - 1];

            string typeName = null;
            foreach (object o in MyRefObjHolder)
            {
                Type type = o.GetType();
                object name = type.GetProperty("Name").GetValue(o, null);
                if (name != null && name is string && (string) name == className)
                {
                    typeName = type.Name;
                }

            }

            //linq based solution, replce the foreach loop with linq one :P
            //string typeName = (from o in myRefObjHolder select o.GetType() into type where type.GetProperty(propName) != null select type.Name).FirstOrDefault();


            return typeName != null ? string.Format("{0}.{1}", typeName, propName) : null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think that would output "Member.Address.Line1"

Comment: now it does, check and lmk!

Comment: its not getting it that way, the object are bound to have a extra property "Name" and the MyRefObjHolder is defined at line # 17 as List<Object>

Comment: try running the above code